# OData Delta used in PATCH cannot update nested object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create a Controller in an Azure Mobile Services project with a Patch method that takes my entity, structured like this:

```
public class Page 
{
        public Page() { }
        public int Color { get; set; }
        public Point Offset { get; set; }
}
```

where the class Point looks like this:

```
public class Point
{
        public Point() { }
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

The model, created with CodeFirst strategy using EntityFramework, produces a table with the columns `Color`, `Offset_X` and `Offset_Y`.

Unfortunately the `Offset_X` and `Offset_Y` columns are not updated when the Patch method is invoked (while they are correctly populated in the Post method).

My PATCH request body looks like this:

```
{
 "Color":16755404,
 "Offset": {
   "X":20.0,
   "Y":40.0
 }
}
```

I am using the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.Data.OData.5.8.3
- Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.8.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.7.0
- Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.2.0.0

How can I make my controller update such properties? Or should I work on the model of the entity?

Any help is very appreciated!!

Comment: Please provide the json payload that you are sending in the PATCH request, just to confirm.

Comment: what version of the mobile services SDK are you using - the answer can be vastly different

Comment: I added the body of the PATCH + the used SDK

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: this answer is for OData v4 provided by the Microsoft.OData.Core nuget package and does not apply to Azure Mobile Services

As it is currently implemented in Microsoft.Data.OData, you cannot patch nested entities, but you can patch properties on an entity that are complex types.
The good news for your model is that Point has already been implemented as a mapped complex type in your Entity Model, but the behaviour you are describing leads me to believe that the OData Model does not share the same interpretation

For your example this is a possible odata model builder statement:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
// Complex Type Overrides
builder.ComplexType<Point>();
// EntitySet Declarations
builder.EntitySet<Page>("Page");
```

It is important when you want to override default interpretations of classes in your model that you declare them *before* your standard EntitySet declarations, otherwise when Page is declared as an EntitySet, it's properties are immediately included into the model, and when you try to declare Point as a Complex Type you will get a runtime error similar to this:

> The type '< your namespace >.Point' cannot be configured as a ComplexType. It was previously configured as an EntityType.

Comment: thanks to your example + the content of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395116/azure-mobile-service-tablecontroller-not-returning-inner-objects/36356262#36356262 I was able to make the GET request work, but still no luck with the PATCH. The problem seems to be that the Delta<Page> object that is the input of the PATCH method cannot recognize the nested object Point and therefore fails in providing the list of Changed vs Unchanged properties

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I also tested this issue on my side and could encounter the same issue as you provided. Also, I found that we could provide the nested object Point with a new `id` property for inserting as follows:

[image]

**TEST:**

[image]

> How can I make my controller update such properties? Or should I work on the model of the entity?

Per my understanding, you could modify the action for updating in your Page TableController and check the nested object Point under `Delta<Page> patch`, update the Point table if the specific Point record exists. But I would prefer handle updating against each table individually. You could follow adrian hall's book about [Relationships](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/). Moreover, you could build your [Custom HTTP Endpoints](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter4/custom/) and implement the additional logic by yourself.

Comment: thanks for your contribution. Actually I would like to avoid having a brand new table for the Point; instead I would just use the Point class as a container for a set of columns that in the DB would be just columns of the Page table.